# How to call an executable with parameters from powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am seeking help on how to call cmd with specific parameters from a powershell script. So far what I have written is below, but it gives me an error message saying $_cmd is not recognized.

I am trying to pass the from date and to date to a an exe... The from date as you can see needs to be today - 1 and the to date should be now. The path of the executable is D:\DataService and that's why I am setting the path early in the script.

```
    Write-Host "Get data from service"

$path ="D:\DataService"

Push-Location $path
$Date = Get-Date
$DateFrom = $Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
$DateTo = $Date.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
$_cmd = "ReportGen.exe -ReportType Data -DateFrom $DateFrom $DateTo"

%$_cmd%
```

Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don't make a command string. Simply use the call operator (`&`):

```
Write-Host 'Get data from service'

$path = 'D:\DataService'

Push-Location $path

$Date     = Get-Date
$DateFrom = $Date.ToString('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
$DateTo   = $Date.AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM-dd')

& ReportGen.exe -ReportType Data -DateFrom $DateFrom $DateTo
```

Comment: The call operator isn't necessary here - only when the command is something else, like a variable.

Comment: @JasonShirk It may not be necessary, but it doesn't hurt either, and I consider it good style to use it whenever you're calling external programs.

Comment: sure, adding/removing '&' won't change how the external command runs.  The operator might hurt script readability, especially for newcomers where any extra syntax can be confusing.

Comment: They'll probably be more confused when they try `$exe = "some.exe"; $exe /with /args` instead of `some.exe /with /args` for the first time.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use `Invoke-Expression` as per the comments below.

```
Invoke-Expression $_cmd
```

Original comment, which is wrong:

Did you try putting an ampersand in front. e.g.:

```
& $_cmd
```

Not sure why you are using the `%` characters.

Comment: The problem with that is that you can't have arguments in the string, because PowerShell interprets the entire string as the name of a command. In fact, that's the primary use of the call operator `&`: to instruct PowerShell to interpret the entire string that follows as the name of a command rather than just the first token (useful if you're specifying a path to the command that has spaces). **Invoke-Expression** evaluates the string as if it were typed at the command prompt.

Comment: Try the following to see the difference: `$c = 'gci c:\' `, then `& $c` -- fails because `gci c:\ ` is not the name of a command. Now try `$c = 'gci'`, then `& $c c:\ ` -- that works (and `& $c` will list the current directory).

Comment: I think you meant `& $c c:\ ` not `& $c c: ` but now I get it.

Comment: It does say that now. You must have been looking at one of the earlier versions of my comment. The mini-markdown of comments can be a pain. I think it was interpreting the backslashes at the end of code spans as escaping the closing backticks, so I had to try several things to get it to display correctly, but I think I got it right in the end. :)

Answer (score 3):

`%$_cmd%` looks like a mixture of PowerShell and cmd syntax. The %'s have no special significance. PowerShell interprets that as the literal name of a command, which of course is not recognized. To execute the contents of the string, use

```
Invoke-Expression $_cmd
```

However, that will only work if **ReportGen.exe** is in the path, and cmd doesn't even get involved, because you're not calling it anywhere. If for some reason, as you say, you specifically want to execute that command with cmd, you should add `cmd /c` or `cmd /k` at the beginning. However, you don't even need to assign to a string, you can just call cmd directly:

```
cmd /c ReportGen.exe -ReportType Data -DateFrom $DateFrom $DateTo
```

`/c` means that cmd will exit after executing the command. `/k` means the cmd prompt will remain open after the command is executed. You probably want `/c` so that you'll return to the PowerShell prompt after executing the script.

Comment: Invoke-Expression should be avoided, see my blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powershell/archive/2011/06/03/invoke-expression-considered-harmful.aspx

Comment: Also - calling cmd is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

A couple things. One, stop using Write-Host. Honestly, let this be the final time you ever use it (unless you truly need it - and know why you need it). Instead, use Write-Output - even when you know your script is going to run in the console. Second, you could also consider using the Start-Process cmdlet and its parameter -ArgumentList.

Comment: I disagree. There are many cases where **Write-Host** is preferable, and many case where it doesn't make a difference. As a rule of thumb, use **Write-Host** to display informational messages to the user, and **Write-Output** for results that you want to be able to use for something else (pipe to another command or a file, or assign to a variable). Anyone coming from a Unix background might think that you should always default to **Write-Output**, but PowerShell's object pipeline orientation often makes it the wrong choice for informational messages.

Comment: I agree with @AdiInbar. There are plenty of cases where **Write-Host** is preferable to **Write-Output**. In fact, you should probably not use **Write-Output** unless you know exactly what you're doing. This could cause unexpected results when capturing output from a function, PowerShell Job, PSSession, etc. Just because you read a blog post by Jeffrey Snover doesn't necessarily mean that, that advice applies universally.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I will be sure to do some more research on this topic... and I sounded like I knew so much. I have to admit that I am intrigued in seeing an example of how Write-Output can cause unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

Your $DateFrom and $DateTo seem to be backwards, since you are making $DateTo set to yesterday. So unless you are going from today to yesterday you may want to adjust that. Also, you specify the from date, but just tack the to date on the end, not sure if you need to specify what it is, or if both dates are a part of the same parameter. As for running a command with arguments, use Invoke-Command with arguments comma delimited as such:

```
Invoke-Command -FilePath "D:\DataService\ReportGen.exe" -ArgumentList '-ReportType Data','-DateFrom $DateFrom','$DateTo'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it something like this.

```
$CustomProcess = New-Object System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
$CustomProcess.FileName = "ReportGen.exe"
$CustomProcess.arguments = "-ReportType Data -DateFrom $DateFrom $DateTo"
[System.Diagnostics.Process]::Start($CustomProcess)
```